# New line character as function parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, character-encoding, ascii

From **Test.html** I include a **test.js** that runs function **d()**. This function has a parameter a string that might contain "new line" characters (10 in ASCII), as per example below. However, when I am debugging this function, vars **s** and **data** include all characters except the new line, i.e., they contain string "HelloWorld" (length 10) instead of "Hello[charNewLine]World" (length 11).

Is there a way to pass a string with new line characters as parameter to a function in Javascript? Thank you.

**Test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=x-user-defined">
<title>JavaScript Scripting</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="x-user-defined" src="test.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function d(s) 
{
    var data = (s + "").split("");
    var dataLength = data.length;
    var t = [dataLength],n;

    for(n=0;n<dataLength;n++)
    t[n]=data[n].charCodeAt(0);
}
d("Hello\
World");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d("Hello\
World");
```

contains a "line continuation".

The [language specification](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.4) says

> The String value (*SV*) of the literal is described in terms of character values (*CV*) contributed by the various parts of the string literal.
>
> ...
>
> The *SV* of `LineContinuation :: \ LineTerminatorSequence` is the empty character sequence.

which means that it contributes no characters to the value of the string literal.

To embed a newline in a string, just use `\n` as in

```
d("Hello\nWorld")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the new line and also pass it in the string, use it this way:

```
d("Hello\n\
World");
```